# How are serializable transactions implemented?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, relational-database, isolation-level

I fail to see how the serializable isolation level can be implemented without locking the entire tables in question - something that appears to be possible as all material on the subject I could find talks about row and range locks.

I found an interesting example in a discussion of the serializable and Sql Server's snapshot isolation levels [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2007/05/16/serializable-vs-snapshot-isolation-level.aspx).

The example is about having two marbles, one black, one white, and two transactions that concurrently change all black marbles into whites and vice versa. My question is: How does the serializable isolation level prevent an outcome where the end result is again one white and one black marble?

I've tried the following on SQL Server:

```
create table marbles (id int primary key, color char(5))
insert marbles values(1, 'White')
insert marbles values(2, 'Black')
```

I now start two transaction, one being

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
BEGIN TRAN

-- returns 1
SELECT id FROM marbles m WHERE m.color = 'White';
UPDATE marbles SET color = 'Black' WHERE id = 1;

COMMIT
```

the other being the analogous:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
BEGIN TRAN

-- returns 2
SELECT id FROM marbles m WHERE m.color = 'Black';
UPDATE marbles SET color = 'White' WHERE id = 2;

COMMIT
```

The selects are meant to resemble reads by a programmatic client that uses the id to later issue the respective update.

If I run both transactions until after the select statement first and then let them continue, they deadlock. This is what we would wish to happen (or at least it's better than the result of mixed colors).

I've tried to change the updates into setting the colors to green and yellow, respectively - and the transactions still deadlock, and this time they really shouldn't. If the white marble is changed to yellow, it would never have been selected by the transaction that was interested in the black marbles - so why the deadlock?

In order to implement serializable properly (locking in exactly the necessary cases) one would have to keep a record of the selects of a transaction in such a way that the database engine could figure how updates of other transactions affect those result sets.

I could see that in simple cases such as in this example or simple range queries, but in the general case it strikes me as a very complicated problem.

What I find puzzling in this regard is that no source I found on the topic mentions this problem. They all just state something to the effect of saying "the serializable isolation level is implemented with clever locking, see range locks" and suggest that this is it. But that's not nearly the whole story, is it?

In particular, when a database engine claims to "support serializable" it's not at all clear what that might be: It could be simple locking of everything on each transaction and it's probably never going to be the other extreme of locking only what is really necessary, as that is too complex to implement.

In contrast, it's clear what exactly Sql Server's snapshot isolation level really means.

I'd be interested if I see that correctly and if so, whether people have pointers to further reads on the subject, especially regarding SQL Server.

[EDIT: A similar question in the postgres world had been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837708/predicate-locking-in-postgresql-9-2-1-with-serializable-isolation).]

[EDIT2: The postgres wiki also has a discussion on this very example [here](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SSI#Black_and_White).]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dbcc traceon(3604,1200,-1)

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
BEGIN TRAN

-- returns 1
SELECT id FROM marbles m WHERE m.color = 'White';

COMMIT

dbcc traceoff(3604,1200,-1)
```

Gives output

```
Process 55 acquiring IS lock on OBJECT: 1:2072783258:0  (class bit2000000 ref1) result: OK

Process 55 acquiring IS lock on PAGE: 1:1:23838  (class bit2000000 ref0) result: OK

Process 55 acquiring RangeS-S lock on KEY: 1:72057594087014400 (8194443284a0) (class bit2000000 ref0) result: OK

Process 55 acquiring RangeS-S lock on KEY: 1:72057594087014400 (61a06abd401c) (class bit2000000 ref0) result: OK

Process 55 acquiring RangeS-S lock on KEY: 1:72057594087014400 (ffffffffffff) (class bit2000000 ref0) result: OK
```

The plan shows a clustered index scan. There are two rows in the table but three key range locks are taken out.

There is no suitable index for the `WHERE` clause to seek in on `color` so the select query effectively ends up locking the whole table. The last lock shown blocks the range up to "infinity" (`ffffffffffff`).

Even if there was a suitable index on "color" and the execution plan used it the exact range locked depends upon what other rows exist in the table (including any deleted "ghost" records not yet cleaned up)

[A more detailed explanation is available here](http://michaeljswart.com/2010/04/transaction-phenomena-part-4-serializable-vs-snapshot/)

Comment: The linked article is one of those I already looked at explaining range locks for ranged queries. That explained how it could be done in specific scenarios, but it still seems that the general case is way more complex. After all, my example doesn't even have a range query and it also could have had two "between" clauses simultaneously - it can get arbitrarily complex.

Comment: @John - Not that complex. Serializable will always end up locking the whole thing (whether via an object level lock or individual range locks comprising the whole index) except if the plan has an index seek . Then individual ranges may be locked.

Comment: I tried adding an index and it again deadlocks in both cases.

Comment: As explained in the article I already linked the exact range locked depends on the rows in the table. If you only have two rows then the "next key" will be the other row. Add some more rows with different colours. Also once you've done that ensure the execution plan is doing a seek on that index.

Comment: Yes, I think I got it now. The other row is the "next row" and hence it's also locked.

A serializable transaction is either locking tables (that's what you mean by object-level locks, right?) or it's using a range on a specific index.

Which means that the existence and choice of indexes have a huge impact on locking issues in the case of this isolation level.

One could almost say that the serialized isolation level is parameterized on an index.

Comment: If I got that right so far, do you know whether all (most?) database engines agree on that notion? It is, after all, conceivable that some do more that than to further reduce the number of rows the locks are covering. Is this (what you and the article explain here) the "standard" way of what is to be done by a "proper" implementation? Is it even defined that way by the SQL standard?

Comment: @John I don't know how it is implemented in other popular DBMSs. Certainly the standard won't specify though. That just defines the logical definition and keeps out of specifying physical implementation. Serializable isolation is best avoided in SQL server in almost all cases. Especially if no suitable index seek can be used. Hence the advice in [using new TransactionScope() Considered Harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2010/05/21/using-new-transactionscope-considered-harmful.aspx)

Comment: Do you know why the article claims serializable to be "rarely useful" in sql server specifically?

Comment: @John - I don't know whether they meant to imply that it is particularly unuseful or deadlock prone in SQL Server compared to other DBMSs. It is true though that I hardly ever find it useful. On the cases where I do need to lock a range I normally use a `HOLDLOCK` hint rather than escalating the whole transaction.