# How to run multiple transactions concurrently in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I want to do some basic experiment on PostgreSQL, for example to generate deadlocks, to create non-repeatable reads, etc. But I could not figure out how to run multiple transactions at once to see such behavior.
Can anyone give me some Idea?

Comment: That depends on which SQL client you use.

Answer (score 9):

Open more than one `psql` session, one terminal per session.

If you're on Windows you can do that by launching `psql` via the Start menu multiple times. On other platforms open a couple of new terminals or terminal tabs and start `psql` in each.

I routinely do this when I'm examining locking and concurrency issues, used in answers like:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12456645/398670
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12831041/398670

... probably more. A useful trick when you want to set up a race condition is to open a third `psql` session and `BEGIN; LOCK TABLE the_table_to_race_on;`. Then run statements in your other sessions; they'll block on the lock. `ROLLBACK` the transaction holding the table lock and the other sessions will race. It's not perfect, since it doesn't simulate offset-start-time concurrency, but it's still very helpful.

Other alternatives are outlined in [this later answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17055880/398670) on a similar topic.

Answer (score 1):

pgbench is probably the best solution in yours case. It allows you to test different complex database resource contentions, deadlocks, multi-client, multi-threaded access.

To get dealocks you can simply right some script like this ('bench_script.sql):

```
DECLARE cnt integer DEFAULT 0;
BEGIN;
LOCK TABLE schm.tbl IN SHARE MODE;
select count(*) from schm.tabl into cnt;
insert into schm.tbl values (1 + 9999*random(), 'test descr' );
END;
```

and pass it to pgbench with -f parameter.

For more detailed pgbench usage I would recommend to read the official manual for  [postgreSQL pgBench](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/pgbench.html)

and get acquented with my pgbench question [resolved recently here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997070/postgresql-pgbench-tool-running-user-defined-sql-script).

Answer (score 0):

Craig Ringer provide a way that  open mutiple  transactions  manualy， if you find that is not very convenient， You can use [pgbench](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/pgbench.html) run multiple transactions at once.

Comment: At first I thought this could be a neat idea, but on reading the documentation of pgbench it's not obvious to me how it responds to the conditions that the OP is trying to test for: "deadlocks, non-repeatble reads, etc." I'd go for Craig's approach.

Comment: Per this later answer you can also use isolationtester from `src/test/isolation`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17055880/398670